# give some explanation about bind() function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I saw the source code in the MSD

```
// Define the original function with four parameters.
var displayArgs = function (val1, val2, val3, val4) {
    document.write(val1 + " " + val2 + " " + val3 + " " + val4);
}

var emptyObject = {};

// Create a new function that uses the 12 and "a" parameters
// as the first and second parameters.
var displayArgs2 = displayArgs.bind(emptyObject, 12, "a");

// Call the new function. The "b" and "c" parameters are used
// as the third and fourth parameters.
displayArgs2("b", "c");

// Output: 12 a b c
```

I can not understand how this source code is working. Bind function can map parameters automatically? Here, it binds two parameters second times.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind Bind can take multiple arguments. The first argument will be used as the value of `this` and the rest of the parameters will be passed in as arguments when the function is invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is always the `this` value that you want to pass and the rest of the arguments are arguments to your function. You can pass these arguments partially.

What that means is if you have the partial arguments now and you want to pass the rest of the arguments later when available, you can do that by having `this` bound function.

HTH.